# POST request to retrieve pdf in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, pdf

I am making a POST request to retrieve a pdf. The request works fine if I do it in postman, but I get an empty pdf if I do it through node.js using the `request` package. Here's my request using the `request` package:

```
let body = {
  attr1: "attr1",
  attr2: "attr2"
}

let opts = {
    url: "some_url",
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body
}


request(requestOpts).then(pdf => {
    console.log(pdf) // prints out the binary version of the pdf file
    fs.writeFileSync("testing.pdf", pdf);
});
```

I use the exact same request parameters when I use postman but it returns the pdf w/ the correct content.

Can someone help? Or is the way I am saving my pdf incorrect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solution - i had to set `encoding: false` in the request options.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fs.writeFileSync("testing.pdf", pdf, 'binary');
```

The third argument here tells fs to write binary rather than trying to UTF-8 encode it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) the third paramter should be a string that represents the encoding.
For pdf files the encoding is 'application/pdf'

So this should work for you : `fs.writeFileSync("testing.pdf", pdf, 'application/psf');`

Comment: Did you mean "psf" within "'application/psf'"?